# How right download file from AWS S3 use JS

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I try to download file from AWS S3, this file downloaded successfuly, but it isn't save in my disk, and I don't get any error.

```
<script>
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import FS from 'browserify-fs';

export default {
  computed: {
    s3Client() {
      // Enter copied or downloaded access ID and secret key here
      const ID = 'RANDOM_ID';
      const SECRET = 'RANDOM_SECRET';

      return new AWS.S3({
        accessKeyId: ID,
        secretAccessKey: SECRET
      })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    downloadFile() {
      const BUCKET_NAME = 'js-bucket'
      const FILE_NAME = 'test.epub'

      const params = {
        Key: FILE_NAME,
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME
      }

      console.info("Try to download file : " + FILE_NAME + " from bucket: " + BUCKET_NAME)

      this.isDownloading = true

      this.s3Client.getObject(params)
      .promise()
      .then(data => {

        FS.writeFile(FILE_NAME, data.Body, function (err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err.code, "-", err.message);
          }
        })

        console.log('File downloaded successfully')
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

In console I see my message about success save:File downloaded successfully. But it isn't right.

Comment: You have `<script>` tags in your code, so I assume you're trying to run this from a browser? Is your S3 resource publicly accessible?

Comment: `browserify-fs` is Node's `fs` implemented on top of level.js, which is a leveldown store fron indexeddb. Are you expecting it to save the file to your computer?

Comment: <script> because it figure from Vue.JS code

Comment: Yeas, i am expect it

Comment: If I use default library, I will see the same result.

Comment: I restart node.JS and now I see this error: TypeError: fs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default.a.writeFile is not a function
    at eval

Comment: In this string  FS.writeFile(FILE_NAME, data.Body, function (err) {

Comment: How are you able to Import 'aws-sdk' I get Module not found when using this

Answer (score 0):

I decided it by myself:

```
  .promise()
  .then(data => {
    const blob = new Blob([data])
    const link = document.createElement('a')
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    link.download = FILE_NAME
    link.click()
    URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href)

    console.log('File downloaded successfully')
  })
```

It work, but if anybody know way to do it better, answer please.